# My release map API key does not function, yet debug key works fine

Tags: android, dictionary

When I upgraded one of the paid apps I wrote for Android Market, the release map API key failed to work. Two unhappy customers downloaded an app which did not display the maps but only a white grid.

This app has three map pages. Substituting the debug-based key, instead of the release key, in any one of the three pages causes it to display properly (also I switched debuggable to true in this case). Everything runs absolutely fine on my development phone using the key based on debug keystore.

I tried generating a new key, actually four others, but none work.

I'm pretty sure that I am doing things properly as I have got release keys before.

I'm afraid to upgrade any of my other posted apps for fear of breaking them too.

One key which fails to work is: 0VhiLw2B2QaOEjTVRmycP6RGHfAtTNQQE6Pioaw

Also non-functional are:
0lrAHi7hTTo7rfdYU8v1AEu4FelcMLbkhlWoYZg
0VhiLw2B2QaOREesqZwlM1lyDkzFmqMQIbL3QcQ
0VhiLw2B2QaNbf3oXAum82nV26Oc12gCdjsQScA 2
0VhiLw2B2QaNOl7XH6GhKn85Tk4k7kB9V6fG61g

I used the following to generate some of these keys:

alias8, Nov 29, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 24:CE:2E:95:64:8B:27:09:6B:06:A6:D8:91:8F:C2:0C
alias5, Nov 29, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 91:64:40:C6:28:9A:10:1F:D5:2E:09:F0:B5:92:11:DB
alias3, Nov 2, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 2E:9A:AF:0C:E3:2A:1C:16:B6:AE:F9:CA:B3:C0:96:6B
alias2, Oct 8, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 17:CA:09:A6:F0:53:E9:A1:AA:99:EB:5F:87:40:51:22

I think this is a bug in the Android Map service. I have wasted a lot of time trying to fix this and was forced to unpublish my best-selling app temporarily.

Any ideas anyone?